# What can I say instead of "zorgi"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

As I understand it, *zorgi* corresponds to all of these:

- to care

  > *Mi ne zorgas.*
  >
  > *Ĉu li eĉ zorgas pri ĉi tiaj aferoj?*
- to take care of

  > *zorgi pri ĝardeno*
  >
  > *zorgi pri infano*
- to worry

  > *Mi zorgas pri vi.*
  >
  > *Kiam panjo ne respondis miajn alvokojn, mi ekzorgis.*

I find this very confusing, since all of the meanings are clearly different but still often used in the same context. Take *Mi zorgas pri mia avino* for example, am I worrying about my grandmother, or am I taking care of her? Also, trying to figure out the meaning of a word like *memzorgema* is rather tricky.

Are there other words that I can replace *zorgi* with?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- to care -> **interesiĝi** (pri)

  > *I do not care about politics*
  >
  > *Mi ne interesiĝas pri politiko*
- to take care of -> **okupiĝi** (pri)

  > *I am taking care of the garden*
  >
  > *Mi okupiĝas pri la ĝardeno*
- to worry -> **maltrankviliĝi** (pri/pro)

  > *I worry about my daughter.*
  >
  > *Mi maltrankviliĝas pri mia filino*

Answer (score 13):

The word *zorgi* is vague, but in many cases, surrounding details make it clear what the situation is. In your example, *Mi zorgas pri mia avino* would usually be followed by something like *Mi volus viziti pli ofte* (in the first case) or *Mi devis transloĝiĝi en ŝian domon* (in the second). However, the word *prizorgi* always implies active involvement, and *maltrankvili* covers the more passive meaning. Note that the accusative can be used instead of *pri*.

- *prizorgi* — to take care of
- *flegi* — to nurse (an ill or incapacitated person, etc)

  - *flegisto* — a nurse
- *varti* — to raise, bring up (a child, young or new thing, etc)

  - *vartejo* — nursery
  - *vartisto* — childcare worker
- *gardi* — to watch, to look after (i.e. keep an eye on)
- *atenti* — to pay attention to

Answer (score 5):

Just to add a bit more detail about a translation of “I don’t care”, I think this English expression is a bit more abrasive than just the opposite of caring. I think if you say “I don’t care about football” there is a hint that you are annoyed that people keep talking to you about football. However if you say “I am not interested in football” it is more neutral and just stating a fact. I think the first phrase is better translated by “mi prifajfas futbalon”.

In summary, to just express your level of (non-)interest in football in a neutral way:

> I’m not interested in football
>
> Mi ne interesiĝas pri futbalo
>
> Futbalo ne estas grava al mi
>
> Mi ne zorgas pri futbalo

Whereas to add a hint of annoyance:

> I don’t care about football
>
> Mi prifajfas futbalon

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is confusing. To distinguish, I say:

- fari al si zorgojn = to worry
- trakti / zorgi pri = to take care of

Por "mi ne zorgas" prefere diru "ne gravas al mi."